# Pass through http headers with node request call

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers

I'm running a site in node, using the npm package `request` to communicate with a rest api service I have on the same server, the thing is I need to pass through to the api the headers received from the site, specifically the ip address, right now since the `request` calls come from the site which is in the same server, all "remote ip" addresses I get on the rest api are localhost (127.0.0.1). I don't know if this is possible, if this already has a name (in which case I would have found the solution easier if knew that 'name') or what? XD, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: If your Site is built using express, you can get the requester's IP address using `req.ip` and then you could in turn pass that to your REST API within a querystring, the body or a custom header.

Comment: Just get the remote IP address in your node request and then add it to a header when calling the rest API service.  The rest API service can then get the original IP from the header.   [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) is a common header that proxies typically use.